# How can I specify to the Z3's optimizer to start the search from the lower bound of the objective function?

Tags: python, optimization, smt, z3py

I'm using Z3 to optimize a SMT problem. I have a variable "h" (obviously bounded by some constraints) that I want to minimize with the Z3 `Optimize` class. The point is that I know the lower bound of h but not its upper bound, so if I write something like

`optimizer.add(h >= lower_bound)`

what happens is that the solver spends **a lot of time** trying suboptimal values of h. If instead I write

`optimizer.add(h == lower_bound)`

the optimizer finds the solution for h fairly quickly if there is one. My problem is that clearly the optimal solution doesn't always have `h == lower_bound`, but it's usually *close* to it. It would be nice if there was a way to specify to the optimizer to start searching from the lower bound and then go up. A workaround that I found consists in using the Z3 `Solver` class instead of the `Optimize` one and iterating over all the possible values of h starting from the lower bound, so something like:

```
h = lower_bound
sat = 'unsat'
while sat != 'sat':
  solver = Solver()
  h_var = Int('h')
  solver.add(h_var == h)
  # all the other constraints here...
  sat = solver.check()
  h += 1
```

But it's not really elegant. Can some of you help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you know an upper bound as well, then you can do a binary search. That'd be logarithmically optimal in terms of the number of calls to `check` you have to make.

If you don't have an upper limit, then first find it by incrementing `h` not by `1`, but by a larger amount to "jump" to an upper-bound. (For instance, increment by 1000 till you hit `unsat`.) Then do a binary search since you'll have upper-lower bounds at that time. Of course a good value for increment will depend on the exact problem you have.

I'm afraid these are your only options. The "official" way of doing this is to say `opt.add(h >= lower_limit)`, which doesn't seem to be working for your problem. Perhaps the above trick can help.

Another thing to try is a different solver: OptiMathSAT has different algorithms and optimization techniques implemented. Perhaps it'll perform better: https://optimathsat.disi.unitn.it